How can I override the first part of @Min err message in Spring (Hibernate Validator - Bean Validation)?
I have an annotation as to not register the negative numbers
@Min(value = 0, message = "{msg.cannot.be.negatif}")
private Integer joursPerturbationDto;

<input type="number" label="Jour(s)" info="nombre de jours" th:field="*{joursPerturbation}" name="joursPerturbation" min="0"/>

msg.cannot.be.negatif=Ne peut pas être négatif


Becaused my field has a label of "Jour(s)", the 1st line of the message uses the name of the field. But I want to display a custom message, without changing the field name.

the custom message for the 1st line should be: "Jour(s) de la durée de perturbation"
Is there a way to override this message?
